# Problems with scanning character matrixes from a file in C

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array

In this simple program my goal is to scan a matrix from a file (called map.dat). For some reason, whenever I am trying to scan it, everything goes smoothly until the 6th row. After it acquires all of the elements in the 5th row it goes on to scan row 6, which works for some time and then when j==10, the elements from row 6 start going into row 5 and then row 9 is deleted from the matrix. I tried scanning it one row at a time using strings, but the result seems to be the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 40

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp=fopen("map.dat","r");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    char m[ROWS][COLUMNS+2];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<COLUMNS+1; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%c",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

This is what's in the map.dat file:

```
........................................
....#####...............................
....#####...............................
....#####...............##############..
....#####.....###.......##############..
....#####.....###.......................
..............###........######.........
..............###........######.........
.........................######.........
........................................
```

Comment: Why all this fuss with `fscanf` when you could just `fread` and parse it yourself? Given how close the desired format is to what's in the file you could do some very light processing on the buffer and have exactly the array you desire from the raw buffer.

Comment: check the return value of fscanf

Comment: @tadman I am a very basic programmer and I'm just studying for my CS class, we have only seen fscanf or fgets, so we're supposed to use these functions when solving this I believe.

Comment: `fscanf` is a crutch you should get rid of as soon as possible. The real potential in C comes from making your own simple parsers, and layering on more complexity if and when that's necessary.

Comment: @4386427 it's returning 1

Comment: Please double check each line ending in your .dat file to be sure it is "\n" and not "\r\n" or some other fun.  You could also trying moving your `m` array to global space, just in case this is some sort of stack weirdness, though an array of 500 bytes or so should be fine.  You could fscanf() a whole string/line at a time as well, but that is probably tomorrow's lesson.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I tried scanning it one string at a time, instead of using nested for loops, but the result is the same.

Comment: It's acting like you are overflowing memory while reading into `m`, but the code I see looks fine.  So, again i ask to double check the .dat - err .txt file (since you are reading "r" mode) to be sure it conforms.  Also, check your return codes from fscanf() when reading your strings to be sure it reads as many characters as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just printed it and it is working just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS 10
#define COLUMNS 40

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp=fopen("/home/avidbots/Desktop/test/map.dat","r");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    char m[ROWS][COLUMNS+2];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<COLUMNS+1; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%c",&m[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<COLUMNS+1; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

   return 0;
}
```